# Change event doesn't working when input text change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onchange

This is my code:

```
<input type="text" id="x">
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#x").onchange(function(){
        alert("x");
    })
});
```

But id doesn't work. What is problem?

Comment: try using `keyup` instead of `onchange` event

Comment: You need to get function call while each key up ?

Comment: `.onchange` is event of javascript. Change event in jquery is `.change`

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
$("#x").onchange
```

to this:

```
$("#x").change
```

There is a `.on()` listner, so this can also be used:

```
$("#x").on('change', function(){
   alert("x");
})
```

---

You have a jQuery object and you have to bind the jQuery methods only. And change event on `input[type=text]` works when you off the focus out of it.

Comment: the OP would still need to focus out of the textbox in order to get this working?

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal seems due to error, nothing was happening, this should work. Although you are also correct, OP has to put focus out of the input to get it working.

Comment: OP did not ask to trigger change on keypress.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.change()` event instead of `.onchange()` event in jquery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#x").change(function(){
    alert("x");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="x">
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `onchange` is javascript. In jquery it's `change`

```
$("#x").change(function(){
                    alert("x");
                })
```

or

```
$("#x").on('change',(function(){
                    alert("x");
                })
```

But to trigger it you should change focus

Answer (score 0):

`$.onchange` is not a function. You are getting confused between native JavaScript, which allows

```
<input onchange="doSomething()"/>
```

and jQuery, which requires

```
$(selector).on("change",function(){...});
```

The correct function is `$.on(event)` where event is a string. In this case you need

```
$("#x").on("change",function(){..});
```